# How do you save an Image so it can be used later in another activity using Android?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera

I have a program which takes a picture and then stores it in the Gallery. Here is the code:

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss");
        String name = "foto_" + df.format(new Date());
        ContentValues werte = new ContentValues();
        werte.put(MediaColumns.TITLE, name);
        werte.put(ImageColumns.DESCRIPTION, "Aufgenommen mit CameraDemo");
        Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                werte);

        OutputStream ausgabe = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
        ausgabe.write(data);
        ausgabe.close();
        camera.startPreview();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Now how can I call this image in another activity so that i can work with it there? I heard 
you could save it in a bitmap but I didnt understandt how.

I know that im missing some basic programming skills but this would really help me out.
If you need more of the code just write it in the comments. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand your code much but You should use Intent.putExtras method to pass bytes to new activity(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20byte[]%29)
or simply save image to sdcard for later use

Comment: yes, but how do I call it, in the new activity? Thats my question

Comment: use getIntent().getByteArrayExtra in new activity for getting byte array.And make Bitmap with BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray from those bytes.